# Unity: how to override parameter for a factory function?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

Consider this example:

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public MyDisposable(int dummy)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

var container = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IDisposable, MyDisposable>();

// in real code this is dependency of type Func<IDisposable>
var factory = container.Resolve<Func<IDisposable>>(new ParameterOverride("dummy", 0));
var disposable = factory(); // this line throws exception
```

The problem is that parameter overrides are not used by an automatic factory.

This resolution works fine, but it is not an option in my case:

```
var disposable = container.Resolve<IDisposable>(new ParameterOverride("dummy", 0));
```

I need to construct the IDisposable implementation via factory, but that implementation requires some arguments for construction. Is it possible to solve this problem without implementing own factory?

Comment: Do you need to call `container.Resolve<Func<IDisposable>>` multiple times, each time with a different value of `dummy`?

Comment: Yes. In my case this call is container.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride("dummy", 0)); where MyClass depends on Func<IDisposable>

Comment: And you want each instance of `MyClass` to have a different value of `dummy`?

Comment: I am not sure. But I think that this is not supported by Unity as is. Is it an option for you to use a custom factory interface instead of `Func`? e.g. `IDisposableFactory`?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to make it generic if possible, I don't want to create a new interface for each injection. Removed confusing `Debug.Assert(dummy == 0);`